# Add contents of geoJson file to vector layer after download

Tags: openlayers-3, geojson

I want to download features in geoJson format from a service and then add the features in it to a new layer on my map. I can download the features ok, I'm stuck as to how to add them to the map after the download.
I do not want to let OL read the file directly from the url as shown in every example I can find, since I want more control over when the features will be downloaded or what to do if the download fails for some reason.
I'm trying this (data contains my geoJson featurecollection):

```
var nwLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'My Title',
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: data.features,
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill( { color: "yellow" } )
        })
    })
} );
map.addLayer(nwLayer);
```

This results in an error somewhere inside the ol library, apparently the ol feature type is not the same as a geoJson feature, it requires a getId() function.
I also tried to add the data as a whole:

```
features: data,
```

This has no visual effect at all.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, OpenLayer features are not GeoJSON feature objects. To transform GeoJSON to OpenLayers features, use the `readFeatures` method of `ol.format.GeoJSON`.

With the rest of your example code:

```
var nwLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'My Title',
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(data)
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill( { color: "yellow" } )
        })
    })
});
map.addLayer(nwLayer);
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I was looking for a function like this in the Vector Layer namespace, but it didn't occur to me it could be found in the GeoJson format namespace. Being rather new to OL I'm a little overwhelmed by the extent of the library and documentation.
It took me a little more time because I had other issues with the data itself.